# Magento 2.1.6 No confirmation emails sent from frontend

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.1.6

Our new installation is not sending confirmation mails of orders in the frontend. Once the order has been placed and there is a successful response from the payment gateway, the customer is shown a message success and that they will receive an email with the order information. This mail however is not sent and I cannot even find the mail when looking at our outgoing mail logs indicating that Magento isn't sending it.

I however do get registration emails sent and if I go into the order in the backend and click on "send email" the mail is delivered. Is this standard / how it's supposed to be or is there a way for me to force the email sent on completion of the order?

Also, if it's standard, how would we get a confirmation mail of a new order on the frontend?

Reference: Our shopping cart uses SMTP to send emails (we're using the https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp) and account is setup and working so doubt it's mail server configuration related.

Comment: Check error log file what is in log when place order

Comment: Nothing noted in the error_log, debug log or systemlog - It's almost like there is no reference of a mail being sent anywhere

Comment: Do you have your cron jobs setup for your store? I'm not positive but I believe magento 2 requires cron for the frontend sending of order emails still like magento 1.9+

Comment: Have you figured this out?  In my 2.1.2 store I was having the same problem.  Like  a ghost.  No errors nothing.  Jist upgraded to 2.1.9 and same issue.  We have to click the "End Mail" button to get Magento to send the email.  All crons are working properly too.

Comment: Any updates? Same issue here....